# Is it 昨日の午後 or 昨日午後

Tags: grammar, particle-の

When using の to describe when something occurred, what is used?

昨日 **の** 午後 or 昨日午後　for "yesterday afternoon"

昨日 **の** 一時 or 昨日一時 for "yesterday at 1 o'clock"

昨日 **の** 午後一時 or 昨日午後一時 for "yesterday at 1 pm"

What about 今日, 明日, etc.

I don't know if they mean anything different, if it's grammatically incorrect, or if one is used conventionally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both patterns are used. 昨日の午後 is the default expression used primarily in conversations and novels. 昨日午後 is a compact style that is particularly preferred for headlines, news articles, formal reports, business emails, and such. Also note that 昨日 is often read as さくじつ instead of きのう in such formal contexts.

The same is basically true with きょう and あした, but I somehow feel あした11時 is common and safe in the most informal conversations.